# Creating recyclerview with variable height of item as per the content text with swipeable feature

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

How to create a recyclerview with items having variable height as per the length of content text like the below image. Recyclerview also supports swipeable items.

Expected

[image]

Actual

[image]

My layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.voiro.phoenix.custom.swipe_layout.SwipeRevealLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/swipe_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:dragFromEdge="right">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rl_mark_read"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/green"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:visibility="visible">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_mark_read"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:drawablePadding="2dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_medium"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/mark_as_read"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            app:drawableTopCompat="@drawable/ic_double_check" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="visible">

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/view_foreground"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/background"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/cl_main_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:minHeight="90dp"
                android:padding="16dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/iv_notification_thumbnail"
                    android:layout_width="36dp"
                    android:layout_height="36dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_avatar"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_notification_title"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
                    android:text="@string/value_place_holder"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/tv_notification_time"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/iv_notification_thumbnail"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/iv_notification_thumbnail" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_notification_time"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
                    android:text="@string/value_place_holder"
                    android:textColor="@color/text_desc"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/tv_notification_title" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_notification_desc"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_medium"
                    android:text="@string/value_place_holder"
                    android:textColor="@color/text_desc"
                    android:textSize="10sp"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/tv_notification_title"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/tv_notification_title"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tv_notification_title"
                    tools:ignore="SmallSp" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/ib_unread_dot"
                    android:layout_width="8dp"
                    android:layout_height="8dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/shape_circle_orange"
                    android:clickable="false"
                    android:visibility="visible"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    </FrameLayout>

</com.voiro.phoenix.custom.swipe_layout.SwipeRevealLayout>
```

If you can see in the actual image the subtext is getting cropped whenever I try to set longer text on title text.
My Actual requirement is I want a layout something like notification tray of android where depending on the size of context list item height adjusts to accommodate the content also the height of swipe layout behind the list item adjusts accordingly.

**I don't want to set height of item programmatically or manually. It should be auto adjusted as per the content length.**

I searched through all over the internet but could not able to find the solution.

Comment: Are you tried like lib sample?
SwipeRevealLayout -  android:layout_height="match_parent"
FrameLayout - android:layout_height="match_parent"

Comment: SwipeRevealLayout is a custom layout for swipeable View extending ConstraintLayout.

Comment: Debug it or share those code here... How others know about your custom view!?

Comment: Custom View has nothing to do with this problem. It will just add confusion.

Comment: All the items looks like same height... In this constraints it looks good... So check your custom view